# Restore WhatsApp messages after deleting the account

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, restore

I deleted my WhatsApp account and I would like to restore the conversation I had. I didn't uninstall the app, or doing any reset.

When I checked the `/databases` folder, it's empty. Is it possible to find the last backup file somewhere?

If it's related, I've got LG G3.

Comment: How did you delete your Whatsapp account? Did you uninstalled the Whasapp application from your phone or you deleted the converstions alone? or Did u factory reset your phone?

Comment: i just pressed the delete account on whatsapp i didnt delete the app or reset anything

Comment: Your messages chat history can be found under `Databases` directory..if that is empty and you have'nt backuped your data previously before deleting your account..then restoring is not possible..

Comment: isnt it supposed to be backedapp automatically?

Comment: yes it will be automatic and the default path is under the `Databases` directory..there are also other third party apps to backup the messages that you have to manually backup..i saying here about the default backup..can you find any backups under that directory?

Comment: my database is empty for some reason and im sure i had a backup befre deleting the account

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23983557/1793718)..Further reading on Whatsapp FAQ..[Recovering messages in Whatsapp and info](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/20887921)..

Answer (score 1):

Go to SDcard or Internal SD (whichever available default). Find WhatsApp folder. The daily scheduled backups that occur at 4.00am is present in the databases folder.

To restore, fresh install WhatsApp. There will be a dialogue "Do you want to restore your chat history?". Click Restore.

Comment: when im looking at the folder i cant find any reminder of a backup file.. and i checked in my computer that i want to see system files and hidden files just in case

Comment: Is there a folder WhatsApp in your phone?(can be SD or internal). If yes check whether the backups folder is empty or not. If its not empty and has files msgstore*.cryp8 files then you can restore your backup after reinstalling whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some file recovery software to recover the deleted `.crypt8` database files on your sdcard, you are out of luck.

Deleting your WhatsApp account will erase your message history from sdcard.

Deleting your account will do the following

```
- Delete your account from WhatsApp.
- Delete you from your friends' WhatsApp Contacts lists.
- Delete you from all WhatsApp groups.
- Erase your message history on your phone.
- Delete your WhatsApp service payment information.
```

[Source](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/21119703)